# UIDatePicker is crashing on value changed

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

I have created a method and connected it with value changed event of UIDatePicker, but as soon as I changed the value the app. crashes.

If I remove the connection of UIDatePicker's value changed to my method in Interface builder, then app does not crash.

Can I not connect value change to my own method for UIDatePicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the code that is present in the Event handler function.

If at all, you have a custom View Controller in your app and you have your picker on the View of this view controller, check in your Nib file, the class name that implements your nib viewController. If it is UIViewController, change the name to the Custom ViewController class name.